# Error on installing Passenger with Nginx and Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: nginx

I am using Ubuntu 22.10 and I get the following error when running the command `sudo apt-get install -y libnginx-mod-http-passenger`:

```
   The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libnginx-mod-http-passenger : Depends: nginx-common (< 1.18.1) but 1.22.0-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

**What I tried so far**

I tried to follow the suggestion from [here](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2263#issuecomment-637686589) and add another APT repository:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger focal main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list'
sudo apt-get update
```

This results in a similar error:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
 libnginx-mod-http-passenger : Depends: passenger (= 1:6.0.15-1~focal1) but 1:6.0.15-1~jammy1 is to be installed
                               Depends: nginx-common (< 1.18.1) but 1.22.0-1ubuntu1.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must reinstall your Ubuntu to 22.04 lts version... Nginx 1.18 is not available in Ubuntu 22.10

Comment: Telling people to downgrade their OS usually isn't a viable solution..

Comment: @ArturMeinild thxs I edited my answer